# System policy prevents writing a disk image to this device

Tags: sudo, live-usb

I get this error while trying to make a LiveUSB from an existing iso.

[image]

I have added `myuser` to sudoers in `/etc/sudoers`

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myuser     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And I enter the password correctly.

I have also tried both `/dev/sdc1` (the destination disk) mounted and unmounted. To be sure I chowned `/dev/sdc1` to be owned by `myuser`.

The same goes for `gparted`. I can not run it as `myuser` but I can when I run it from command line `sudo gparted`.

So I'm wondering why this error happens and  how it be fixed?

Comment: I assume you rebooted or logged out and back in after adding your user to sudoers?  That requires a relogin or a reboot to refresh your current user permissions/groups

Comment: Yes I did reboot  but to no avail.

Comment: Found it! This solved the problem immediately (running as root): `adduser myuser sudo` . Apparently user need to be added to sudoers group manually.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem immediately (running as root):

```
adduser myuser sudo
```

Apparently user needed to be added to sudoers group manually.